# Redirect using Html returned by api

Tags: javascript, api, axios

Is it possible to redirect a page using the HTML response returned by an API? An API that I'm using returns Html and I need to use this response for redirection.
I've tried using

```
window.location.href = response.data
```

but it's not working. And the response of API

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate">
<body onload="document.order.submit()">
<!--body-->
    <form name="order" action="https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay" method="post">
    <p> <h2>Please wait.. your payment is processed.........</></p>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_AccessCode" value=""/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Amount" value="00"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Command" value="pay"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Locale" value="en"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Merchant" value=""/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_ReturnURL" value="/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_Version" value="1"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_card" value="Visa"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_gateway" value="ssl"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_SecureHash" value="E0989722822D8439C98CC17045A53173405C786CCF5DE5430DC419688A0E9D69"/>
<input
type="hidden" name="vpc_SecureHashType"
value="SHA256">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is returned?

Comment: @Teemu I have updated my question with the semple response

Comment: Print your response to console `console.log(response.data);` and see whats going wrong...Or add the output to your post

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the contents of your current page like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = response.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your problem description, I don't think redirect is the way to do it, You can do one of two things:

1) Replace the body tag content of the page with the new content.

```
document.body.innerHTML = response.data;
```

2) Use iFrames. Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: The iFrame option isn't much different, you still need to set the innerHTML with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your server can use redirect mechanism using HTTP response object. Like in nodejs

```
res.redirect("/login.html");
```

where `res` is `HTTP` response object.

But if you are returning the entire HTML then

```
window.location.href = response.data
```

will not work as `window.location.href` expects an URL not the html content.

Another way if you are returning the HTML content is to replace the body of your page by using

```
document.body.innerHTML = response.data;
```

Comment: He never said he's using node.js on server side.